# convert string to hexadecimal string

Tags: java, hex

i have a string of int value like "131008130225002" i need to convert it to hexadecimal string. I tried various ways,

1. output of toHex function is 313331303038313330323235303032 but i do
   not need it,
2. i need in  hexadecimal format using ABC upto 12 places.
3. I tried Integer.tohex, but it is out of range of integer
4. In case of Double.tohex it gives 0x1.dc9ad4424da8p46

My friend is doing same job in ios using **unsigned long long** as datatype and **0x%02llx** regular expression to convert nsstring

code is:

```
String x="131008130225002"; 
System.out.println(x);
    // System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(x));
     System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(x));
     System.out.println(Double.toHexString(Double.parseDouble(x)));
     String a1= toHex(x);
     System.out.println(a1);
```

toHex function:

```
static String toHex(String arg) {
    try {
        return String.format("%12x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Is your string a decimal number that you want to convert to hex?  Or is a sequence of decimal numbers, of which you want to convert each one separately to hex? Show the expected output for your input.

Comment: it is a combination of decimals retrived from different places, now i want to convert it to hex and pass as a parameter

Comment: @HimanshR post **the exact result you want to see from the conversion** A single exact result says more than 1000 words, post that please...

Comment: @Hitmansh You are not making it any clearer.  Show the exact result you want to achieve with your input.

Comment: sorry for my incapability to explain and thanks for your efforts, but answers below are exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String x = "131008130225002";
System.out.println(new BigInteger(x).toString(16));
```

The output is 7726b510936a.

Answer (score 1):

It will fit in a `long`, so you can use `Long.toHexString`.

```
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong("131008130225002")));
```

For a more generic solution, `BigInteger` also has [a `toString` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29) which takes in a radix (16 being hex of course).

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("131008130225002").toString(16));
```

Both of the above print out `7726b510936a`.